# Check programmatically if device has NFC reader

Tags: android, nfc

Is there a way to check at run time whether a device has an NFC reader? My app uses NFC to perform a task, but if no reader is present, it can perform the same task by using a button.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Hope This works for you

```
NfcManager manager = (NfcManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NFC_SERVICE);
NfcAdapter adapter = manager.getDefaultAdapter();
if (adapter != null && adapter.isEnabled()) {

    //Yes NFC available 
}else if(adapter != null && !adapter.isEnabled()){

   //NFC is not enabled.Need to enable by the user.
}else{
   //NFC is not supported
}
```

Comment: You might want to differentiate between `adapter == null` (no reader exists) and `!adapter.isEnabled()` (the reader has been turned off). This way, the user could be prompted to enable the NFC adapter.

Comment: ya '@323go' it always depend on the individuals, is that developer needs that or not, if he don't want to show popup simple he will check only with adapter != null condition i think it not a big deal

Comment: I disagree. You could provide a *complete* answer, and let the developer decide what the target audience is.

Answer (score 12):

The simplest way to check if an Android device has NFC functionality is to check for the system feature `PackageManager.FEATURE_NFC` ("android.hardware.nfc"):

```
PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();
if (pm.hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_NFC)) {
    // device has NFC functionality
}
```

However, there exist devices (at least one of Sony's first Android NFC smartphones has this issue) that do not properly report the `FEATURE_NFC`. (That's those devices that do not allow you to install apps that require NFC functionality through Play Store does such a check for apps that require NFC.)

Therefore, the more reliable solution is the one described by [Sainath Patwary karnate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23564553/2425802). To check if a device has NFC functionality (or rather if a device has a running NFC service), you can use:

```
NfcAdapter nfcAdapter = NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(context);
if (nfcAdapter != null) {
    // device has NFC functionality
}
```

If you also want to check if the user enabled NFC on their device, you may use the `NfcAdapter`'s `isEnabled()` method. But be warned that it's not always as easy as described by [Sainath Patwary karnate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23564553/2425802). Particularly on Android 4.0.*, the `isEnabled()` method sometimes throws undocumented exceptions when the NFC service had crashed before, so you might want to catch those exceptions. Moreover, on Android >= 2.3.4 and < 4.1 (I could not reproduce the problem on later versions but that does not mean it is not there!), the first call to `isEnabled()` after the NFC service had been stopped or crashed always returned `false`, so it is advisable to always ignore the result of the first call of `isEnabled()`.

```
if (nfcAdapter != null) {
    try {
        nfcAdapter.isEnabled();
    } catch (Exception e) {}
    bool isEnabled = false;
    try {
        isEnabled = nfcAdapter.isEnabled();
    } catch (Exception e) {}
    if (isEnabled) {
        // NFC functionality is available and enabled
    }
}
```

Comment: but nfc service could crash arbitrarily, or only in particular situation?

Comment: Typically, on devices with NXP chipset, the NFC service often crashes when communication with a card is interrupted or when the phone does not properly recognize a card (e.g. because the card does not receive sufficient power).

Answer (score 2):

Here's my function that I use for detecting NFC presence.

```
public static boolean deviceHasNfc() {
    // Is NFC adapter present (whether enabled or not)
    NfcManager nfcMgr = (NfcManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NFC_SERVICE);
    if (manager != null) {
        NfcAdapter adapter = manager.getDefaultAdapter();
        return adapter != null;
    }
    return false;
}
```

As stated in @Sainath's answer you can also detect if the NFC is enabled using `adapter.isEnabled()`

Answer (score 1):

For those of you doing Kotlin here is a quick enabled check extension following the rules posted above

```
fun Context.isNfcEnabled(): Boolean {
    val nfcAdapter = NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(this)
    if (nfcAdapter != null) {
        return try {
            nfcAdapter.isEnabled
        } catch (exp: Exception) {
            // Double try this as there are times it will fail first time
            try {
                nfcAdapter.isEnabled
            } catch (exp: Exception) {
                false
            }
        }
    }
    return false
}
```