# How to check a device's nfc capability

Tags: java, android, nfc

For an android app that I'm writing, I need to adapt a display based on the nfc capability of the device. Basically, I need to know first if nfc is available, and then to know which features are available (just reading tags, or card emulation,...)

I thought it would be in NfcManager or NfcAdapter but I can't find the right way to perform these tests.

Anyone could help? Many thanks!

Comment: See [Check programmatically if device has NFC reader](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23564475/2425802). There is an equivalent feature for card emulation as well.

Comment: https://www.developer.com/ws/android/nfc-programming-in-android.html