# Check if device is compatible NFC in flutter app

Tags: flutter, nfc

I am using the `flutter_nfc_reader: ^0.1.0` package to read nfc tags in my mobile application but i can not find any method to check if the device supports NFC so that i can display a message

Link [to the package](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_nfc_reader)

Comment: The docs don't mention any API related to NFC availability. You can easilty write your own method channel with code similar to this (link for android only) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23564475/check-programmatically-if-device-has-nfc-reader

Comment: The author didn't specify whether the package is production ready, but 0.1.0 version suggests it is not in release yet

Comment: Please post an answer if you find a soluton

Comment: There are more developed nfc flutter packages like https://github.com/semlette/nfc_in_flutter  which has `NFC.isNDEFSupported` check to check if Android or iOS support NFC.

Answer (score 0):

You can copy paste run full code below 
To check if the device supports NFC you can
Step 1: Use git ref `master` channel, https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_nfc_reader#installation

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_nfc_reader:
    git:
      url: https://github.com/matteocrippa/flutter-nfc-reader.git
      ref: master
```

Step 2: Use `FlutterNfcReader.checkNFCAvailability()`, and will return `available, disabled, not_supported`
code snippet

```
  NFCAvailability available;

  checkNFCAvailability() async {
    available = await FlutterNfcReader.checkNFCAvailability();
    setState(() {});
  }

  @override
  initState() {
    super.initState();
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
      checkNFCAvailability();
    });
```

working demo

[image]

full code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_nfc_reader/flutter_nfc_reader.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Material App',
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Material App Bar'),
        ),
        body: Center(child: NfcScan()),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class NfcScan extends StatefulWidget {
  NfcScan({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _NfcScanState createState() => _NfcScanState();
}

class _NfcScanState extends State<NfcScan> {
  TextEditingController writerController = TextEditingController();
  NFCAvailability available;

  checkNFCAvailability() async {
    available = await FlutterNfcReader.checkNFCAvailability();
    setState(() {});
  }

  @override
  initState() {
    super.initState();
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
      checkNFCAvailability();
    });

    writerController.text = 'Flutter NFC Scan';
    FlutterNfcReader.onTagDiscovered().listen((onData) {
      print(onData.id);
      print(onData.content);
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    // Clean up the controller when the widget is removed from the
    // widget tree.
    writerController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        Text(available.toString()),
        TextField(
          controller: writerController,
        ),
        RaisedButton(
          onPressed: () {
            FlutterNfcReader.read(instruction: "It's reading");
          },
          child: Text("Read"),
        ),
        RaisedButton(
          onPressed: () {
            FlutterNfcReader.write(" ", writerController.text).then((value) {
              print(value.content);
            });
          },
          child: Text("Write"),
        )
      ],
    );
  }
}
```